# Result of Powershell Script sent via email

Tags: powershell, azcopy

On the result of running the below script, it returns the following:

[image]

How could I get this result sent via email? I'm not sure how to get the result into a parameter that I can pass into the Body of an email script:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6

```
$azPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy\"

Set-Location $azPath

$StorageAccountName = "#"

$StorageAccountKey = "#"

$ContainerName = "#"

$SourceFolder = "#"

$DestURL = "https://$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$ContainerName"

$Result = .\AzCopy.exe /source:$SourceFolder /dest:$DestURL /BlobType:block /destkey:$StorageAccountKey /Y /S /XO

$Result
```

Comment: You could use [ConvertTo-Html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html?view=powershell-5.1) for your `$result` and use the result of this for the parameter `-Body` and provide the switch `-BodyAsHtml`.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf - would you mind purposing that as an answer with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either store your result in a file and send it as an attachment:

```
$Result | Out-File Result.txt
Send-MailMessage -From 'User01 <user01@fabrikam.com>' -To 'User02 <user02@fabrikam.com>' -Subject 'Sending the Attachment' -Body "Forgot to send the attachment. Sending now." -Attachments .\Result.txt -SmtpServer 'smtp.fabrikam.com'
```

Or send the content of `$Result` (=string[]) as a string in the `-Body`:

```
$body = $Result -join '`n' # Join result to a single string with line breaks
Send-MailMessage -From 'User01 <user01@fabrikam.com>' -To 'User02 <user02@fabrikam.com>' -Subject 'Sending the Attachment' -Body $body -SmtpServer 'smtp.fabrikam.com'
```

Or (as stated in @Olfa's comment) convert it to HTML and add the `-BodyAsHtml` switch:

```
$body = $Result | ConvertTo-Html
Send-MailMessage -From 'User01 <user01@fabrikam.com>' -To 'User02 <user02@fabrikam.com>' -Subject 'Sending the Attachment' -Body $body -SmtpServer 'smtp.fabrikam.com' -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: Error "Unexpected token '`n` #' in expression or statement." with your second option. Could you please advise?

Comment: Also get:

CovertTo-Html : The term 'CovertTo-Html' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks , much appreciated.  Get the following error though: "Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter '
Specified method is not supported."

Comment: Which option are you using?

Comment: Sorry, its the Convert to HTML one. I'm using azcopy 8.1